# Adding custom time to date

Tags: ruby

the timestamp is in a format that I am not able to add to the ruby date. How can I do this?

```
 sd=Date.parse('2016-01-01')
 z="4:00am"
```

How do I add z into sd?

Comment: Hint: `.to_time` and then adjust it, or instead parse it as a `Time` in the first place. A `Date` cannot hold time information. It's not what it's for. See also: DateTime or Time.

Comment: i tried it but cannot figure how to add the z to it?
sd.to_time
=> 2016-01-01 00:00:00 -0500

Comment: Why not just add it to the string, then parse it as a `Time` directly?

Comment: interesting idea. here we go!! Does it automatically adjust for Daylight savings?
irb(main):579:0> DateTime.parse(sd.to_s + " " +  z)
=> #<DateTime: 2016-01-01T04:00:00+00:00 ((2457389j,14400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Comment: How could it? Some times are ambiguous without the time-zone given for parsing. Anything between 1am and 2am on some days is a grey zone. There are two possible interpretations for `"2022-11-06 01:15am"` in the EST5EDT time zone. The time is parsed using your local time-zone setting by default, so outside of the DST flip periods you should be fine.

Comment: I avoid using parse because `Date.parse("it might work but maybe it won't") #=> #<Date: 2023-05-01 ((2460066j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. Better to use [DateTime#strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).

Answer (score 2):

You can't add time to date but you can parse time like this (just concatenate date and time)

```rb
date = '2016-01-01'
time = '4:00am'
```

```rb
require 'time'

Time.parse("#{date} #{time}")
# => 2016-01-01 04:00:00 +0300
```

To avoid some parsing misinterpretation you can explicitly point directives

```rb
DateTime.strptime("#{date} #{time}", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%p')
```

Comment: I ran your code in irb and found that there's no `parse` method on time.

I checked the docs and couldn't find mention of `Time.parse` there too. Only when I googled did I find this page, where it says we need to `require 'time'` for the parse method to be available: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html

Leaving this here because it might be helpful to others too. And if you edited your code to have `require 'time'` in there, I think that would be very helpful.